grub2: which /boot/efi/EFI/*/grub.cfg does it read?
I have a dualboot linux, fedora and almalinux.
After installing almalinux, I couldn't see the fedora's kernel versions, just multiple entries of Fedora.
Most of the links I found are wrong.

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/grub2-bootloader/#_setting_default_entry_for_grub2

They tell me to use /boot/grub2/grub.cfg but this entry is only for BIOS-based boot, not EFI.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/ch-working_with_the_grub_2_boot_loader#sec-Introduction_to_GRUB_2

Tells clearly we should use /boot/efi/EFI/*/grub.cfg.
Which one should I use in the case where I have multi linux? /boot/efi/EFI/almalinux/grub.cfg or /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg?
What if I have multiple instances of fedora?

edit each grub.cfg file with  identifying text ... see which one loads at boot time

There should be a command or a way to know without altering anything, I'm pretty sure efi/grub doesn't choose the folder randomly.

This sudo efibootmgr -v should show at least two UEFI boot entries and uses GUID/partUUID to finid ESP. One for each of your installs. If you have two installs of same system, then the UUID in grub.cfg in the ESP will be the default boot. You can manually edit that grub.cfg as it is just a three line entry, & uses UUID & configfile to find grub.cfg in your install. Ubuntu, but grub should be the same: https://askubuntu.com/questions/792413/how-to-set-grub-from-second-linux-distribution-as-default-in-uefi-boot

That's what I'm looking for! Thanks!

perhaps one of the enviroment variables described  at https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html
